# 1990s era movie about people tranforming into bird-like creatures?

Tags: story-identification

The movie is based on a futuristic type of world (maybe out of space or not). They had a reddish looking shark creature that flies into the girl's apartment (they fly over the city and are used as weapon). The creature can live out of water. The houses/homes/apartments are suspended in the air.

The movie had a man who eventually mated with the girl and she give birth to a child who can transform into a bird/pigeon. The man can also transform.

There was a scene where the man hid in the girl's bathroom and she hid the platform of the bathroom; when the authorities came in her apartment they asked her where is her bathroom, she said she gave up showering a while back. Do you know the movie?

Answer (score 4):

[Immortal (Ad Vitam)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immortal_(2004_film))  from 2004. The parts you mentioned are not in the Wikipedia synopsis, but I am confident it's the right one.

> The film takes place in New York City in the year 2095 where
>   genetically altered humans live side by side with unaltered men and
>   women, and where Central Park has been mysteriously encased in an
>   "intrusion zone" where people who attempt to enter are instantly
>   killed. A strange pyramid has appeared over the city; inside, the gods
>   of ancient Egypt have judged Horus, one of their fellow gods, to cease
>   his immortality.
>
> ...
>
> Horus is given a limited time to interact with the humans of New York
>   and procreate.

The red sharks are called Dayak. You can see an image below:

[image]